# Reputation went down

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

In stackoverflow I had 603 reputation. However when I come to my computer after a little while I end up with 558 reputation. No one gave me a down vote. Is there a reason why?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One of your answers was removed and you lost 45 reputation. Visit your reputation history and make sure the "show removed posts" box is checked, you'll see it there.

Comment: Your reputation is 658, not 558.

Comment: @chuex: He just got the Association Bonus of +100 when he created his Meta account.

Comment: @animuson Yes you are right! I'm sorry for a stupid question. I was just confused.